# Using properties variable in HTML/JavaScript file in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am working on Spring MVC 3.x. Can we use properties files contents in HTML/JavaScript file?

I have a properties file at the classpath named webMessages.properties.

And Spring -servlet.xml has

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/jdbc.properties,classpath:/webMessages.properties" />
```

When I try to access the properties in the JavaScript file, it is not giving any output:

```
<p>"${topPath.topHeading}"</p>
```

Kindly advise, if this is possible?

Comment: Have you seen this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-resource-bundle-with-resourcebundlemessagesource-example/)?

Comment: What view resolver are you using? JSP? Velocity? FreeMarker? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if context:property-placeholder will expose properties outside the definitions. But I was able to get it by the following way:

```
    <bean id="propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:/jdbc.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:/webMessages.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <context:property-placeholder
        properties-ref="propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer"
        ignore-resource-not-found="true"/>
```

In your jsp:
Include this tag:

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
```

and then access the property as:

```
    <spring:eval expression="@propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer.getProperty('topPath.topHeading')" />
```

Comment: I got this error: `org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 20): Method call: Method getProperty(java.lang.String) cannot be found on org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer type`. And in my `\spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar` I don't see this method.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is possible, but the file needs to be a JSP. Inside the JSP try the following:

```
${properties['topPath.topHeading']}
```

Comment: I even tried <p><c:out value="${properties['topPath.topHeading']}" /> </p>.. but no output.